# Selenium - Log in and navigate to different page

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to log into facebook, and then open a specific facebook url to get a list of people, working for a specific company (e.g. to get the employees of google, I need to go to https://www.facebook.com/search/str/google/pages-named/employees/present/intersect
) My first thought was to simply login (which works fine), and then go to the specific page using driver.navigate().to()

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    WebElement emailElement = driver.findElementById("email");
    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElementById("pass");

    emailElement.sendKeys("xxxx@xxxx.com");
    passwordElement.sendKeys("xxxx");

    emailElement.submit();

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/google/pages-named/employees/present/intersect");
```

However, this way, the facebook page is not available, and I’m prompted to log in again, even though the page is opened in the same browser tab?!

The second thought was to log in first, get the cookie, and then use is this cookie for a new driver:

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    WebElement emailElement = driver.findElementById("email");
    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElementById("pass");

    emailElement.sendKeys("xxxx@xxxx.com");
    passwordElement.sendKeys("xxxxx");

    emailElement.submit();

    Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

    FirefoxDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();

    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        Cookie cookieNew = new Cookie.Builder(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue()).expiresOn(cookie.getExpiry())
                .isHttpOnly(cookie.isHttpOnly()).isSecure(cookie.isSecure()).path(cookie.getPath()).build();

        driver2.manage().addCookie(cookieNew);
    }
    driver2.get("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/google/pages-named/employees/present/intersect");

}
```

However, that way, an exception is thrown:  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: Document is cookie-averse

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a mandatory to store cookies to `to get a list of people, working for a specific company`. The following code block works well at my side :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Log In']")).click();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/google/pages-named/employees/present/intersect");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Console Output :

```
Facebook Search
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked!
However, i changed 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Log In']")).click();
to
    driver.findElementById("loginbutton").click();
as the value of the input is depending on the language

Answer (score 0):

Apply **First Thought:** 
Setting up `geckodriver` for `Selenium Java` resolves the issue I think.

It needs to set `geckodriver` path with `FirefoxDriver` as below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH/TO/geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

> - Download geckodriver for your suitable OS from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
> - Extract it in a folder of your choice
> - Set the path correctly as mentioned above

After submit() you need to use wait functionality to refresh the page like

```
emailElement.submit();      
//Use WebDriver wait.until() or sleep() to finish the submit action
driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/google/pages-named/employees/present/intersect");
```